# SwiftUI - Appending FetchedResults to new array gives an error: "Accessing StateObject's object without being installed on a View."

Tags: arrays, swift, swiftui, core-data

I need to create new array using objects from Core Data.
When I am trying to do that, I am getting an error (purple warning) on line:

```
for item in items {
```

Warning message:

> Accessing StateObject's object without being installed on a View. This
> will create a new instance each time.

My app runs, but it results in empty array.

**Expected result: New array with all the objects from Core Data.**

**How to make it work?**

Data model in this example is very simple: 1 entity: Item with 1 attribute: text: String.

EXAMPLE CODE

**ContentView.swift**

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

struct Item2: Identifiable {
    let id: UUID
    var text: String
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext

    @FetchRequest(
        sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Item.text, ascending: true)],
        animation: .default)
    private var items: FetchedResults<Item>
    
    var items2 = [Item2]()
    
    init() {
        for item in items {
            items2.append(Item2(
                id: UUID(),
                text: item.text!
            ))
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(items2) { item2 in
                    Text(item2.text)
                }
            }
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem {
                    Button(action: addItem) {
                        Label("Add Item", systemImage: "plus")
                    }
                }
                ToolbarItem(placement: .destructiveAction){
                    Button(action: deleteAll) {
                        Image(systemName: "trash")
                            .foregroundColor(.red)
                        //                      .accessibilityLabel("Delete")
                    }
                }
            }
            Text("Select an item")
        }
    }

    private func addItem() {
        withAnimation {
            let newItem = Item(context: viewContext)
            newItem.text = "List item"

            do {
                try viewContext.save()
            } catch {
                // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
                // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
                let nsError = error as NSError
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func deleteAll() {
        items.forEach(viewContext.delete)
        
        do {
            try viewContext.save()
        } catch {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            let nsError = error as NSError
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView().environment(\.managedObjectContext, PersistenceController.preview.container.viewContext)
    }
}
```

Comment: ”items” doesn’t exist inside the init try onAppear

Comment: @loremipsum Thanks, I've tried that. But when I add the code from init to .onAppear, I see different error:
`Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: 'self' is immutable`
And if I change var items2 to @State private var items2 - it works, but list doesn't update.

Comment: The State only gets initialized with the values what updates do you expect?

Comment: @loremipsum I expect to see new array with all the objects from Core Data.
What else should I do to make onAppear work as you suggested?

Comment: Try a print statement with the items count just before the loop. Are there items in the FetchRequest?

Comment: @loremipsum print(items) in init gives me the same error. "Accessing StateObject's object without being installed on a View."
But if change ForEach to use items from FetchRequest - yes, I can see items on the list.

Comment: This code doesn’t have a StateObject there is something missing. Make sure the StateObject is at the level of a SwiftUI struct.

Comment: Why do you map your Core Data objects to a struct? `NSManagedObject` is identifiable, just adopt the protocol.

Comment: @vadian Normally I don't need to create a separate array using Struct. But for one app I need to create a list of entries from 2 different Core Data entities. So I need to append all the objects to another array.

Comment: You can use entity inheritance to get multiple entities in one fetch request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one solution :) Credits to my good friend and awesome iOS developer Yasuhito Nagatomo ([AtarayoSD](https://twitter.com/AtarayoSD) on Twitter)

The solution is very simple. I just needed to use computed property instead of init().

Here's the code:

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

struct Item2: Identifiable, Equatable {
    let id: Int
    var text: String
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext

    @FetchRequest(
        sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Item.text, ascending: true)],
        animation: .default)
    private var items: FetchedResults<Item>
    
    var items2: [Item2] {
        items.enumerated().map {
            Item2(id: $0.0, text: $0.1.text!)
        }.reversed()
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(items2, id: \.self.id) { item2 in
                    Text(item2.text)
                }
            }
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem {
                    Button(action: addItem) {
                        Label("Add Item", systemImage: "plus")
                    }
                }
                ToolbarItem(placement: .destructiveAction){
                    Button(action: deleteAll) {
                        Image(systemName: "trash")
                            .foregroundColor(.red)
                    }
                }
            }
            Text("Select an item")
        }
    }

    private func addItem() {
        withAnimation {
            let newItem = Item(context: viewContext)
            newItem.text = "List item"

            do {
                try viewContext.save()
            } catch {
                // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
                // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
                let nsError = error as NSError
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func deleteAll() {
        items.forEach(viewContext.delete)
        
        do {
            try viewContext.save()
        } catch {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            let nsError = error as NSError
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView().environment(\.managedObjectContext, PersistenceController.preview.container.viewContext)
    }
}
```